# - [NSBundle pathForResource:ofType] works differently for directories on 10.7 and 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsbundle

I had this code

```
NSString *path = @"foo/bar"; // Note this is a directory, not a file!
NSString *pathInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:nil];
```

It was working fine on 10.8 (returning the path found in the bundle) but returned nil in 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in both OSes):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[path pathComponents] lastObject]
                                ofType:nil
                           inDirectory:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
```

*NOTE: `lastObject` and `stringByDeletingPathComponents`* are nice in this case because not crashing with an index out of bound, but rather returning nil!

Originally I thought that this would make it, but it does **NOT**:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nil ofType:nil inDirectory:path];
```

This returns the first element found in the path (a file or folder), which is totally not what I wanted.

I guess Apple "tweaked" the implementation of `pathForResource:ofType:` since 10.8 to make it work with directories as well, so depending on wether or not you still need to support 10.7, you know what you should use.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, like an easier way of getting back a directory (again, in 10.7, since in 10.8 it's super easy like I state in the question).

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for finding the path to any item in a subdirectory of the bundle, including the appropriate localised variant, in 10.6 -> 10.8 at least:

```
// long hand...
NSString *item = [path lastPathComponent];                          // path/item -> item
NSString *itemBase = [item stringByDeletingPathExtension];          // base[.ext] -> base
NSString *itemExtension = [item pathExtension];                     // base[.ext] -> ext or @""
NSString *pathDirectory = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]; // path/item -> path
NSString *pathInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:itemBase
                                                         ofType:itemExtension
                                                    inDirectory:pathDirectory];
```

The allowance for `pathForResource:` to be a path appears to be an (undocumented?) extension in 10.8; it would be best to avoid using it unless you find it is documented.